# Once installed, how do I activate Firebug in Mobile Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, motorola-droid-2, debug

I went to the getfirebug.com web site, where I was able to install Firebug under Firefox 1.10.6 (the Beta version of Firefox from the Play store).  It said the install was successful.  Now what?  How do I activate Firebug?  There are no new icons that I can click on like there are on the desktop version, and long-clicking on the page isn't doing anything either.  I see no new menu options either.  In the add-ons menu I see Firebug, but it only offers the choice to disable or uninstall, so I know it's there and installed.